# Spring Boot, JPA/Hibernate DTO, ManyToOne

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, dto

This is my first project with Spring/Spring Boot. It's a simple bookmark service with User and Bookmark entities. For each controller, a DTO is created and validated upon creation/post. If the DTO is valid, I instantiate a new User or Bookmark.

The issue I am having is that when I create a new bookmark, the user_id column in the bookmark table is null. I'll post code starting with the two domain objects, the DTOs and the controllers.

User

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private String username;
private String password;

@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private String email;

@Column(name = "role", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Role role;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private List<Bookmark> bookmarks;

public User() { }

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

//getters and setters and toString.
}
```

Bookmark

```
@Entity
public class Bookmark {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String url;

@Column(length = 2048)
private String description;

@ManyToOne()
private User user;

public Bookmark() { }

//getters and setters and toString.
}
```

User DTO

```
public class UserCreateForm {

@NotEmpty
private String username = "";

@NotEmpty
private String password = "";

@NotEmpty
private String passwordConfirmation = "";

@NotEmpty
@Email
private String email = "";

@NotNull
private Role role = Role.USER;

//getters and setters and toString.
}
```

Bookmark DTO

```
public class BookmarkCreateForm {

@NotEmpty
@URL
private String url="";

private String description="";

private Long userId;

public BookmarkCreateForm() { }

//getters and setters and toString.
}
```

Really only the bookmark controller matters here, so I'll skip the UserController, but can add it if needed.

BookmarkController

```
@RestController
public class BookmarkController {

private final UserService userService;

private final BookmarkSerivce bookmarkSerivce;

@Autowired
public BookmarkController(UserService userService, BookmarkSerivce bookmarkSerivce) {
    this.userService = userService;
    this.bookmarkSerivce = bookmarkSerivce;
}

@RequestMapping("{userId}/add")
public Bookmark addBookmark(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId, @RequestBody BookmarkCreateForm form) {

    User user = userService.getUserById(userId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException(String.format("User=%s not found", userId)));

    System.out.println(form.getUserId());
    Bookmark bookmark = bookmarkSerivce.create(form);

    return bookmark;
}
```

}

And the BookmarkServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class BookmarkServiceImpl implements BookmarkSerivce {

private final BookmarkRepository bookmarkRepository;

@Autowired
public BookmarkServiceImpl(BookmarkRepository bookmarkRepository) {
    this.bookmarkRepository = bookmarkRepository;
}

@Override
public Bookmark create(BookmarkCreateForm form) {
    Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark();
    bookmark.setUrl(form.getUrl());
    bookmark.setDescription(form.getDescription());

    return bookmarkRepository.save(bookmark);
}
}
```

Comment: Please show the code of the BookmarkService.

Comment: Sorry about that, dunni. Added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was being an idiot. The solution is simple and I realized it after dunni asked me to post the BookmarkService.

The BookmarkCreateForm (the DTO) didn't have a User property. So in the BookmarkService, when setting the properties of the Bookmark object, user never gets set. Obviously JPA/Hibernate aren't able to map a non-existent user.

Code:

```
public class BookmarkCreateForm {

@NotEmpty
@URL
private String url="";

private String description="";

private User user;

public BookmarkCreateForm() { }

//getters / setters
}
```

BookmarkService

```
@Service
public class BookmarkServiceImpl implements BookmarkSerivce {

private final BookmarkRepository bookmarkRepository;

@Autowired
public BookmarkServiceImpl(BookmarkRepository bookmarkRepository) {
    this.bookmarkRepository = bookmarkRepository;
}

@Override
public Bookmark create(BookmarkCreateForm form) {
    Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark();
    bookmark.setUrl(form.getUrl());
    bookmark.setDescription(form.getDescription());
    bookmark.setUser(form.getUser());

    return bookmarkRepository.save(bookmark);
}
```

}

BookmarkController

```
@RestController
public class BookmarkController {

private final UserService userService;

private final BookmarkSerivce bookmarkSerivce;

@Autowired
public BookmarkController(UserService userService, BookmarkSerivce bookmarkSerivce) {
    this.userService = userService;
    this.bookmarkSerivce = bookmarkSerivce;
}

@RequestMapping("{userId}/add")
public Bookmark addBookmark(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId, @RequestBody BookmarkCreateForm form) {

    User user = userService.getUserById(userId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException(String.format("User=%s not found", userId)));

    form.setUser(user);
    Bookmark bookmark = bookmarkSerivce.create(form);

    return bookmark;
}
```

}